# checkboxes in tablerow pushed off screen by textview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-layout

I have the following code that is a foundation for a listview.

The idea is to have a checkbox that is always aligned to the right of the screen. Should the text to the left of it be too long I would like it to be ellipsized "..." or cut off gracefully.

It works fine as long as the text is short but not as is when the text is long. Any advice?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:stretchColumns="0"
>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="This is a very very long title 12345678"      
        />

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure why you are using a TableRow but you are better of wrapping the TextView and Checkbox in a Linear layout and set layout_width to 0dip and use android:layout_weight to set the ratios of both the textview and the checkbox.

eg:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="3" android:text="TextView"></TextView>
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"></CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work well. The reason why I used a table layout is because all I really wanted to do is have a list with right aligned checkboxes and then Google led me to this example: http://huuah.com/using-tablelayout-on-android/

When I do it the way you have recommended it works but text is cut off on the next line. This is not a biggie for now. It's difficult to show on this example because you have to have more than one item in the list...